# How to get the indexpath when the tableview editbutton is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I have 2 tableviewController. In the first tableview I am displaying the values from my database in tableview cell. In the first tableview on the navigation bar their is an edit button so that when I click on the editbutton my tableview changes to edit mode so that all its cells can be edited.

In the second tableview controller there is a switch button. When I change the switch button to off/on the image on the firsttableview controller also changes but the problem is when I click on the edit button and go to the secondviewcontroller and change the switch button of the first row, then it should change the image of the first row but the problem is it always changes the image of last row irrespective of row.

This is my code:

This is code of my firsttableviewcontroller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mimageButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 30, 30)];
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mimageButton setTag:indexPath.row];
        [mimageButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];

    }
    cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    al = [appDelegate.snoozearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.mTimeLbl.text = al.Alarmtime;
    cell.mMessageLbl.text = al.AlarmMessage;
    cell.mRepeatLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Every%@", al.adays];
    cell.mPenalyLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Snooze:%@",al.Penaltytype];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

     return cell;
}
```

This is my setediting code. When I click on the edit button this action is performed:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [mTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];



        if (editing)
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        [self.mTableView reloadData];

    }
    else {
        appDelegate.changeimagetype = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"boolchange"];
        if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == YES)
        {

            [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == NO) 
        {

            [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        if (appDelegate.snoozearray)
        {
            [appDelegate.snoozearray release];
        }
        appDelegate.snoozearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
        [Alarm getInitialDataToDisplay:[appDelegate getDBPath]];
        [self.mTableView reloadData];

}

}
```

This is my secondcontroller cod where switchbutton is present and when I change this switchbutton simultaneous image is changed on the firsttablecontroller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self.switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    if (app.changeimagetype)
    {
        [switchControl setOn:NO];
    }
    else {
        [switchControl setOn:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}



-(void)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL switchchng;
    if (switchControl.on)
    {   switchchng = NO;
        [userdefaults setBool:switchchng forKey:@"boolchange"];
        [switchControl setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        switchchng = YES;
        [userdefaults setBool:switchchng forKey:@"boolchange"]; 
        [switchControl setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [userdefaults synchronize];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you're setting `mimageButton` each time to a new value (for each new cell you create).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mimageButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 30, 30)];
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mimageButton setTag:indexPath.row];
        [mimageButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
    } ...
```

I presume that you change the image here:

```
if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == YES)
{
  [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == NO) 
{
  [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

If this is the case, `mimageButton` will most probably be the button for the last cell (since that's the last one that was initialized, each cell having a unique reuse identifier).

Instead, you should be changing the image like this (where `tableview` is your first tableview):

```
TAlarmCell *cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:0 inSection:0];
UIButton *iButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView.subviews lastObject]; // as @vakio mentioned below, it will be safer to use tags to fetch the right subview, 'lastObject' might return the wrong view in some situations, depending on what TAlarmCell does internally
 if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == YES)
{
  [iButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (appDelegate.changeimagetype == NO) 
{
  [iButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Anyway, you should be reusing the cells if possible (`NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];` causes the cells to not be reused, creating a separate cell for each row), and have an array which objects represent a single cell (e.g: array of NSNumber(BOOL), where each NSNumber(BOOL) tells you if the cell image should be displayed or not).

The [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) might be helpful.

Comment: This is correct, except `cell.contentView` should be `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]`. Also, setting tag to  indexPath.row is wrong because all views start with tag 0 so row 0 will have tag 0.

Comment: oh.. right, for some reason I've read `cell.contentView = mimageButton;` (which wouldn't have worked since is readonly). Will update, thanks.

Comment: where should i write this code in the TAlarmCell *cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexpathWithRow:0 inSection:0];

Comment: replace the similar part from `else` `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated`. Instead of `tableview`, use `mTableView`.

Comment: @babbidi from first view to second view it is working properly.But from second view to first view it is not working i.e when in the second view when i change the switch button of the first row,the image change gets applied on second row.

Comment: @Rani Sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean. All cells initially start with `@"alarm_ON.png"` image. `TAlarmCell *cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:0 inSection:0];
UIButton *iButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView.subviews lastObject];` gets the image button from the first cell, and from the code you posted and the update from above, only the first cell would change the image to `@"alarm_OF.png"`. Unless you're setting the images from other parts of code as well, I don't see where the issue is.

Comment: @Rani I am also not getting it properly.Please edit or code and q properly.